# Open port on Centos 8

Tags: linux, centos8

I am trying to run a service on port 61009 on localhost on centos8, but getting connection refused. I tried opening the port using firewall-cmd command. The output of the firewall-cmd --list-all looks like the following.

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 61008-61010/tcp 61022-61024/tcp 61009/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

My OS details are as follows.

```
NAME=“CentOS Linux”
VERSION=“8 (Core)”
ID=“centos”
ID_LIKE=“rhel fedora”
VERSION_ID=“8”
PLATFORM_ID=“platform:el8”
PRETTY_NAME=“CentOS Linux 8 (Core)”
ANSI_COLOR=“0;31”
CPE_NAME=“cpe:/o:centos:centos:8”
HOME_URL=“https://www.centos.org/”
BUG_REPORT_URL=“https://bugs.centos.org/”
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT=“CentOS-8”
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION=“8”
```

telnet localhost 61009

```
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

How can i open ports on centos8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check port status

   ```
   netstat -na | grep 61009
   ```
2. Check port status in iptables

   ```
   iptables-save | grep 61009
   ```
3. Add the port

   ```
   # vi /etc/services
   service-name  port/protocol  [aliases ...]   [# comment]
   ```
4. Open port in the firewall

   ```
   # firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=61009/tcp --permanent
   success
   # firewall-cmd --reload
   success
   # iptables-save | grep 61009
   -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 61009 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
   ```
5. Check added port status

   ```
   lsof -i -P |grep http
   netstat -na |grep 61009
   ```